# How can I pass input data(string) and save without any page loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`User` has_one `UserProfile`, and `UserProfile` has a column called `message`

Here, I want to save input data of `message` field without any page loading.

As you see  my **View**, It access to `message_update` via put in background when I press `Update` button.
In **Controller**, how can I receive the input data, and save it to the column `message` of `user_profile` table?

I have no idea how to code it in **Controller**:(

I think I'm almost there:) 
Can anyone show me how to code it?
Thanks!

**Contorller**

```
def message_update

    current_user.save

    if request.xhr?  # ajax request
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js {render :action=>"message_update.js"}
        end
    else
        redirect_to users_path
    end


end
```

**View**

```
    <%= form_for(current_user, :url => {:controller => "users", :action => "message_update" }, :remote => true, :class => 'form-search') do |f| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |profile_form| %>
            <div class="input-append">
                <%= profile_form.text_field :message, :class => 'span6' %>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Update</button>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**Routes**

```
get 'message_update' => 'users#message_update', :via => :put
```

and now, this is getting routing error:(

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/message_update"):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change routing to

```
put 'message_update' => 'users#message_update'
```

Explanation

You trying to update existing user (since it's current_user) so you should use HTTP PUT verb that is reserved to update objects.
In Rails 4 you could also write

```
patch 'message_update' => 'users#message_update'
```

but it's just syntactic sugar (alias for put)

Also, you have an error in yous controller. Since you only want to save one field value, I'd recommend writing

```
current_user.user_profile.update_attribute :message, params['user']['user_profile_attributes']['message']
```

Comment: It still won't save input data:(

Comment: I may be wrong with the params key, but you could see what it should be in logs.

Comment: Thanks it returned this error  `NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):`

Comment: log says this `"user"=>{"user_profile_attributes"=>{"message"=>"test", "id"=>"1"}`

Comment: It worked with this `current_user.user_profile.update_attribute :message, params['user']['user_profile_attributes']['message']`!!! why not user_profile????

Comment: This is a rails convention so you could distinguish model attributes from associated model attributes array. Read more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
get 'message_update' => 'users#message_update', :via => :put
```

to

```
match 'message_update' => 'users#message_update', :via => :put
```

Comment: Thanks now there's no routing error but it still won't save input data:(

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying your route as a get request.  Change it to:

`match 'message_update' => 'users#message_update', :via => :put`

Comment: Thanks now there's no routing error but it still won't save input data:(

Comment: okay, I type "aaaaaa" into input field `message` and press the button. Then I load page again. It shows default string:(